# Laravel eloquent multiple relationships to find max date less than x days, using eager loading

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using Laravel, and I have a simple task of find all rooms that haven't been cleaned in the past x number of days.

I need to use Eloquent and eager loading, and the result should ONLY include results with child records, for example if all the rooms in Building 1 have been cleaned in 'x' days, Building 1 should not be returned at all...

**Buildings**

```
+----+---------------+
| id | building_name |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | Building 1    |
|  2 | Building 2    |
+----+---------------+
```

**Rooms**

```
+----+-----------+-------------+
| id | room_name | building_id |
+----+-----------+-------------+
|  1 | Room 1    |           1 |
|  2 | Room 2    |           1 |
|  3 | Room 3    |           2 |
+----+-----------+-------------+
```

**maintenancelog**

```
+----+-------------------+---------+---------------------+
| id | maintenance_value | room_id |      created_at     |
+----+-------------------+---------+---------------------+
|  1 | Cleaned           |       1 | 2015-09-01 00:54:59 |
|  2 | Cleaned           |       1 | 2015-09-06 01:55:59 |
|  3 | Cleaned           |       2 | 2015-09-02 02:56:59 |
|  4 | Cleaned           |       2 | 2015-09-07 03:57:59 |
|  5 | Cleaned           |       3 | 2015-09-03 04:58:59 |
|  6 | Cleaned           |       3 | 2015-09-08 05:59:59 |
+----+-------------------+---------+---------------------+
```

**Building Model**

```
class Building extends Model
{
    public function rooms() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Room');
    }
}
```

**Room Model**

```
class Room extends Model
{
    public function maintenancelog() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Maintenancelog');
    }

    public function needCleaning() {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Maintenancelog')->whereRaw('id in (select                  id from (select id, max(created_at) as created_at from maintenancelog
group by id having created_at <  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)) x')
    }
}
```

**maintenancelog Model**

```
class Room extends Model
{

}
```

**Controller**

```
use App\Room;

$result = Room::has('needCleaning')->with('needCleaning')->get(); //this seems redundant?
```

While I can get the Room and corresponding maintenancelog records,

1. the controller code seems redundant (both `has()` and `with()`) referencing the same method...
2. I'm also not quite sure how to start off with Building and then rooms etc so that I have all (and only) the buildings->rooms->maintenancelogs that are relevant, all others are not included in the collection.
3. The Room model seems a little clunky using whereRaw??  Should this logic be in the maintenancelog model instead?  the query is clunky as well
4. Is there an easier or better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I think I'm trying too hard to fit everything into eloquent instead of relying on the controller...?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

model

```
Class Building extends Eloquent
{
    public function Rooms()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Room');
    }
}

Class Room extends Eloquent
{
    public function MaintenanceLogs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('MaintenanceLog');
    }
}
```

code

```
//set number of days before
$no_days = 5;

//get the start date where room was not cleaned
$start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-'.$no_days.' days', strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))));

//start eager loading
$query = Building::with(
                                array
                                (
                                    'Rooms' => function($qry)
                                    {
                                        $qry->with('MaintenanceLogs');
                                    }
                                )
                             );

//get all rooms that has
$query->whereHas('Rooms', function($qry) use ($start_date)
{
   //exclude room that has  maintenance log within this period date
   $qry->whereDoesntHave('MaintenanceLogs', function($q) use ($start_date)
   {
        $q->where('created_at', '>=', $start_date);
    });
});

$data = $query->get();
```

it will search for room that has no maintenancelog in 5 days

I am not sure how to do a nested scope though